# Cannot GET error message showing using Rest Api in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rest

I am working with nodejs and using expressjs framework,Right now i am trying to run "Rest Api"
but i am getting following error

```
Cannot GET /published
```

Here is my routes file

```
module.exports = app => {
  const tutorials = require("../controllers/tutorial.controller.js");
  var router = require("express").Router();
  router.get("/published", tutorials.findAllPublished);
  };
```

Here is my controller

```
exports.findAllPublished = (req, res) => {
 res.send('Hello world');
};
```

Comment: You have to use `app.use(router)` somewhere

Comment: @Konrad kindly update my post so i can check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the router somewhere in your app: `app.use('/', router)`

This:

```js
module.exports = app => {
  const tutorials = require("../controllers/tutorial.controller.js")
  var router = require("express").Router()
  router.get("/published", tutorials.findAllPublished)
  app.use('/', router) // e.g here
}
```

Should work.